# Linux distribution with out-of-the-box exFAT support

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, live-usb

I have to create a live USB media I can boot a machine with that has no network devices. At the same time, it has to be capable of writing to/reading from exFAT formatted devices. I had to find out that in most Linux distributions (newest Ubuntu, openSUSE,...), this is not a supported feature by default. Is there any Linux distribution that supports exFAT by default or any way to install fuse-exfat on the live USB media in a way that it remains installed across reboots?

Any answers are appreciated
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Being not support by default, and not compiled directly in the kernel and present as a module are quite different things.

Answer (score 1):

Knoppix (>= 7.0.4) has exFAT-fuse support.

Answer (score 1):

Elementary OS, Linux Mint, Puppy Linux, Linix Lite has exFAT support out of the box. You can check weather a distro has certain package or not without installing that distro is to search in https://distrowatch.com/index-mobile.php

**Edit:-** The Linux kernel has native support for exFAT beginning from adaption 5.4. From Kernel 5.7 new exfat driver added for larger media format, recommend using exfatprogs tool to manage exFAT filesystem.
Read more about it [here](https://blog.esper.io/android-dessert-bites-27-exfat-on-pixel-532176849/?)